# How can I understand this code defined in C program?

Tags: c, memcpy

I have 3 arrays A1, A2, A3 defined in C program, with size of 1500, 980, 980 respectively. A1 initialized by the indices of elements in ascending order, A2 - by the indices
too, but in descending order. At the moment after initialization of A1 and A2 these actions are performed:

```
int* A3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * SZ_A3);

memcpy(A3, A1, sizeof(int) * SZ_A3);

memcpy(A3 + SZ_A3 / 2, A2, sizeof(int) * (SZ_A3 / 2));

printf("%i", *(A3 + (SZ_A3 / 2)));
```

There are definitions of SZ_A#:

```
#define SZ_A1 1500
#define SZ_A2 980 
#define SZ_A3 980
```

Which value will be in the standard output stream?

> Answer: 979

I would like to know why the answer is 979. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SZ_A1 1500
#define SZ_A2 980
#define SZ_A3 980
int main(void) {
    int i, A1[SZ_A1], A2[SZ_A2];
    // inicializo el array A1 en orden ascendente por sus indices. from i = 0 to i = SZ_A1-1
    for (i = 0; i < SZ_A1; i++)
        A1[i] = i;
    // inicializo el array A2 en orden descendente por sus indices. from i = SZ_A2-1 to i = 0
    for (i = SZ_A2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        A2[i] = i;        
    int* A3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * SZ_A3);
    memcpy(A3, A1, sizeof(int) * SZ_A3);
    memcpy(A3 + SZ_A3 / 2, A2, sizeof(int) * (SZ_A3 / 2));
    printf("%i", *(A3 + (SZ_A3 / 2)));
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand the lines

```
memcpy(A3, A1, sizeof(int) * SZ_A3)
```

What is the value of A3?. With memcpy, `sizeof(int) * SZ_A3` bytes to be copied, then from memory area A1 to memory area A3?.

```
memcpy(A3 + SZ_A3 / 2 + 1, A2, sizeof(int) * (SZ_A3 / 2));
```

Comment: `A3` is the address of the array that was allocated in the line `int* A3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * SZ_A3);`

Comment: Your explanation of the line is correct, what makes you think you don't understand it.

Comment: The value of A3 after this line `memcpy (A3, A1, sizeof(int) * SZ_A3)`Sr

Comment: When I run the program it prints `0`, not `979`.

Comment: `A2` doesn't contain descending numbers. They're assigned in descending order, but the values are also descending. So `A2[0] == 0, A2[1] == 1, etc.`

Comment: In other words, either the code is wrong or the answer is wrong.

Comment: The answer of the problem is 979 I created the code, I just added the initializations of A1 and A2

Comment: How can I edit A2 in order to initialized by the indices of elements in descending orde, Sr

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < SZ_A2; i++)  A2[i] = SZ_A2-i-1;`

Answer (score 1):

```
memcpy(A3, A1, sizeof(int) * SZ_A3)
```

copies the first 980 elements of `A1` into `A3`. So `A3` now contains sequential numbers up to `979`.

```
memcpy(A3 + SZ_A3 / 2, A2, sizeof(int) * (SZ_A3 / 2));
```

`A3 + SZ_A3 / 2` is the address of the middle element of `A3`, i.e. `&A3[SZ_3 / 2]`, which is `&A3[490]`. So this copies the first 490 elements of `A2` into the second half of `A3`.

So `A3` now contains sequential numbers from `0` in indexes `0` through `489`, and then repeats them from indexes `490` through `979`.

Finally, it prints `*(A3 + (SZ_A3 / 2))`. This prints `A3[490]`, which is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the `array A2` in descending order of its indices which you can easily do it like this:

`A2[i] = SZ_A2-i-1;`

i.e. `A2[0] = 979, A2[1] = 978, A2[2] = 977, ... , A2[978] = 1, A2[979] = 0`

Hope this will help you understand the code better.